# How to make a generic method for obtaining enum items in an ushort object

Tags: c#, generics, enums

The idea is to perform a bit-wise scan of an `ushort` provided to **find any and all matches** within an `enum collection`.

The code I developed is as follows:

```
public List<T> GetEnumItemsFromUshort<T>(ushort input) where T : struct, IComparable, IConvertible, IFormattable
    {
        var output = new List<T>();
        foreach (T enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
        {
            if ((input & enumValue.ToUInt16(new CultureInfo("en-US"))) == enumValue.ToUInt16(new CultureInfo("en-US")))
            {
                output.Add(enumValue);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

As you can see, I use a generic type to define the return type.

I searched the site and found that constraining the generic type with the following `struct, IComparable, IConvertible, IFormattable`, makes it behave like an `enum`.

The code generates a list of the enum provided to contains the matches found.

Then it proceeds to scan the input value to find any and all items that masked (a bit-wise operation as stated before) do match.

If a match is found it adds the enum case to the return list.

I want to know whether this is a good or bad implementation and ways to make it better, it performs as expected but I feel like there's room for optimization.

Comment: Wouldn't this question fit [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) better?

Comment: Yeah, you are totally right, excuse my fault, thanks for the help!

Comment: Voting to close, reposted on Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/111011/13424 (without migration)